# Textarea form missing up formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

My company moved from one ticketing system to another and the textarea formatting is all missed up.

The work log in the picture below shows the old ticketing system (top img) which is pretty and the second work log (bottom img) is removing the formatting. The host identity output from the server is using spaces and not tabs.

I'd like to create a greasemonkey script to fix this issue but I don't know what's causing it. Any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the `<textarea>` use a fixed width font:

```css
textarea {font-family: Monaco, 'Courier New', courier, monospace !important;}
```

To add this in the GreaseMonkey Script, use the `<link />` inserting script, this way:

```
var css = "textarea {font-family: Monaco, 'Courier New', courier, monospace !important;}",
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

And give the default heading parameters of UserScript.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks so much.